# Can I justify paying for an unfunded master's if I'm changing disciplines from undergrad?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding, humanities

I'm in a predicament. I'm about to turn 29. I finished undergrad a few years ago and have been working in what jobs I can since then. I got an undergrad degree in a completely different field than what I hope to eventually get a PhD in: my BA was in English, but I applied for graduate programs in Near Eastern Studies/Civilizations/Archaeology with the ultimate goal of getting a PhD in archaeo/history of art. I was advised against applying directly to a PhD because I don't have a background in archaeo/Near Eastern Studies, which I agree with, even if many PhD programs give you a master's on the way, I still have nothing to prove in the field yet. So I applied for terminal MA programs with the plan of doing a thesis and then applying directly to PhD programs.

Thing is, since I have basically nothing to prove in the field, I actually ended up getting into some really solid terminal MA programs--without funding. I got into Yale's 2-year MA Archaeology program and would get to do a legit thesis and take classes with grad students for about $50k. Obviously I've applied for external funding so still waiting on that. But in my case, does it make sense to pay for a master's given that I have to transition into another discipline?
Thanks!!

Comment: Is this for US study? And, who advised you against a direct doctoral application. In the US, I might advise otherwise.

Comment: Yes, this is in the US. I even reached out to POIs who told me I'd need more experience through a master's first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ... no one but the OP can make this decision. It's a personal trade off between pursing an academic interest versus finding employment.

Answer (score 8):

The general advice is plain and simple.

DO NOT GO TO GRADUATE SCHOOL IN THE HUMANITIES.

The job market is absolutely brutal.  There are several PhD graduates for every permanent academic position available.  Since many people are applying for a permanent position for several years after their PhD, until they give up, there are several hundred applicants all applying for the same five or ten jobs that are looking for someone in a specialty that you are remotely qualified for.

Getting even a full-time temporary position is difficult.  Part time positions pay you about $3000 per course - good luck surviving on that.

Keep in mind the vast majority of universities have precisely zero faculty in archaeology or Near Eastern Studies - you're looking at about 100 total departments around the country, most of which have 3-5 faculty members, which means they're each hiring about once a decade.  That's if most of them don't end up closing down by the time you finish your PhD - every year some school or another announces they'll close a few of their less popular humanities departments.

There are precisely zero non-academic positions for which a PhD in Near Eastern Studies is a better qualification than your BA in English and several years of experience, which you could get starting right now and get paid for it.

Now - if spending ten years in poverty, making no savings towards retirement, ending up almost certainly competing for the same jobs you are competing for now is worth it to be learning and researching your favorite topics for those ten years - I'm not going to argue too hard against your preferences.  However - doing that and accruing $100K (counting interest) or $500K - if you go on to an unfunded PhD - in debt that you'll basically never have the ability to pay off (which means you'll never be able to borrow money for anything else, such as a house) is foolhardy in the extreme.

I agree this is all really sad, and our society ought to do more to support scholarship and education in all of these areas.  If I ever somehow get a $10 million windfall I'd endow humanities research.  Unfortunately, we live in the world we live in.

Comment: I would generally agree. I did an unfunded 1 year MPhil to help prepare me for doctoral programs but I was changing from humanities to an in-demand scientific field with many academic and non-academic job opportunities when I finish. Unfortunately, when it comes to this we do have to think strategically.

Comment: "several PhD graduates"  You mean several hundred or several thousand, right?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: The numbers are not that bad - for philosophy (a reasonably large market for which the professional association keeps decent statistics, in part because it's a well-defined discipline for which statistic-keeping is relatively easy) there are about 3 new PhDs per permanent academic job advertised.  Statistics can be found at https://www.apaonline.org/members/group_content_view.asp?group=110435&id=918649 - of course as I mentioned, this still means  there will be 100 people applying to the same 10 jobs in your specialty.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I did not realize there were so few philosophy PhD graduates.  I do wonder how many of the advertised jobs actually resulted in a hire - searches are cancelled sometimes.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: I think a bigger issue is that some searches end up hiring someone who already has a permanent job elsewhere.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I fear you've made a leap here by conflating the possible cost/benefit ratio of an unfunded archaeology masters degree with a personal view of future post PhD job prospects which wasn't part of the question. I have a mphil and PhD in archaeology and am gainfully employed (and even much respected!). Poster: I'm American did an unfunded MPhil in the UK which was buckets cheaper than the US. I used it to springboard a funded archaeo PhD, and now I am professor so-and-so. Consider looking outside the US. Europe is cheaper and tons US archaeos do their masters in Europe.